# SharePoint Master page permissions

Tags: sharepoint, master-pages

Manipulating Master Page on SharePoint Top Site.

I have Full Control and Design permissions and I am a Site Owner on the Top Site in our site collection, but I am unable to see or change anything on the sites Master Page. I think the problem may lie with the fact that I don't have access to half of the subsites under the main site. Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that you are in as a Site Collection administrator to rule out a permission issue?

Comment: I am a site collection administrator, part of the site owners group as well has having full control and design permissions on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the Publishing feature at the Site Collection level and the root site level.  That should activate the Master page gallery in the Site Settings menu.